# curl to retrofit2 post command

Tags: android, curl, oauth, retrofit

I'm trying to get an access token from the gfycat api. Following their [docs](https://developers.gfycat.com/api/?curl#client-credentials-grant) I'm able to get a good token in terminal with the following command.

```
curl -v -XPOST -d '{"client_id":"YOUR_ID_HERE", "client_secret": "YOUR_SECRET_HERE", "grant_type": "client_credentials"}' https://api.gfycat.com/v1/oauth/token
```

However when trying to to get the same results with my retrofit client the response body is null. Here's my code:

```
public class GfycatApiManager {
    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://api.gfycat.com/v1/";
    private static final String GRANT_TYPE = "client_credentials";
    private static final String CLIENT_ID = "my id";
    private static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "my secret";

    private GfycatApiInterface api;

    public GfycatApiManager() {
            api = (new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build())
                    .create(GfycatApiInterface.class);
        }

        public  void getToken(){
            Call<AccessToken> call = api.getAccessToken(GRANT_TYPE, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<AccessToken>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<AccessToken> call, Response<AccessToken> response) {
                    //System.out.println(response.body().token_type);
                    //System.out.println(response.body().scope);
                    //System.out.println(response.body().expires_in);
                    //System.out.println(response.body().access_token);
                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<AccessToken> call, Throwable t) {}
            });

        }
}
```

And the service...

```
public interface GfycatApiInterface {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/oauth/token/")
    Call<AccessToken> getAccessToken(@Field("grant_type") String grantType,
                                     @Field("client_id") String clientId,
                                     @Field("client_secret") String clientSecret);
}
```

And the token...

```
public class AccessToken {

        @SerializedName("token_type")
        @Expose
        public String token_type;
        @SerializedName("scope")
        @Expose
        public String scope;
        @SerializedName("expires_in")
        @Expose
        public int expires_in;
        @SerializedName("access_token")
        @Expose
        public String access_token;

    }
```

Not sure if it's a problem in my post command or somewhere else but I can't figure it out. Please help :D

Comment: try to make fields private and use standard setters and getters in your model class of `AccessToken`   by using `Alt+Insert`

Comment: adding getters/setters and making private made no difference. response.body() is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make the call using the @Body annotation. The following changes make it work for me :

GfycatApiInterface.java - remove the initial forward slash in the path and change the signature

```html
public interface GfycatApiInterface {

    @POST("oauth/token/")
    Call<AccessToken> getAccessToken(@Body TokenRequest tokenRequest);
}
```

TokenRequest.java - New model class that holds the request parameters

```html
public class TokenRequest {

    private String grant_type;
    private String client_id;
    private String client_secret;
    
    public TokenRequest(String grantType, String clientId, String clientSecret) {
        this.grant_type = grantType;
        this.client_id = clientId;
        this.client_secret = clientSecret;
    }
    
}
```

The getToken() call in GfycatApiManager.java should be using :

```
Call<AccessToken> call = api.getAccessToken(new TokenRequest(GRANT_TYPE, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET));
```

Comment: The format of the POST body was the issue - you were sending it as form parameters (like Name=John+Smith&Grade=19) while the examples in the documentation sent the body data in JSON.

Comment: Gotcha... Thanks!